# GetProcessId returning zero

Tags: c#, handle, pid

I've got an array full of process handles, and am now trying to obtain the relevant process IDs for each of them.

However, all my Process Ids are coming back as zero.
Anyone able to point out what obvious issue I am missing ?

Many Thanks

The 'child' array is populated with process Id's thus :

```
currChild = FindWindowEx(hParent, prevChild, null, null);
```

Then I try to get the process ID:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; ++i)
 {
      handle = children[i];
      pid = GetProcessId(handle);
      Console.WriteLine(children[i].ToString("X") + " : " + pid.ToString());
```

APIs :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcessId", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetProcessId(IntPtr handle);
```

Output:

```
2417E2 : 0
B20D9A : 0
48108C : 0
8809D6 : 0
B5140E : 0
4207F6 : 0
4213B0 : 0
5D15DA : 0
etc ....
```

Comment: does your program has enough rights? try to run it with administrative privilages

Comment: What is `handle`? What is `children`?

Comment: Checking for errors is never optional when you pinvoke, you don't have the friendly .NET exceptions to keep you out of trouble.  GetProcessId() indicates failure by returning 0.  Fix your pinvoke declarations and add SetLastError = true.  And throw Win32Exception when you get a failure indication.  Discovering the bug in your program now becomes easy.

Comment: Hans, thanks for the tips ... I'll get hose added:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `GetProcessId` accepts as input a *process* handle, not a *window handle*
For the latter, you can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` instead.

See [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Marton, you're absolutely right.
What a lame error to make.
Maybe a break, some coffee and rub my eyeballs will help.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @user3379697 Yeah, sometimes the correct solution is just a 30 minute power nap away.